# How to update a Django html element with javascript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to update an html element on web page with javascript. When the home page loads, it works perfectly, but when I click on *New Product* link just the context string is displayed on the home page

**html**

```
<!--  product/home.html -->
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Test context</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Test context</h1>
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}
                Product: <span id="product-code"></span>
                <p><a href="{% url 'new-product' %}">New Product</a><p>
            {% endblock content %}

            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/product.js' %}"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
# cardplay/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView, NewProduct

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view()),
    path('new-product', NewProduct.as_view(), name= 'new-product'), 
]
```

**views.py**

```
# /product/views.py

import random

from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

class HomePageView(View):
    template = 'product/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        context = {}
        return render(request, self.template, context)

class NewProduct(View):

    def get(self, request):
        code = random.choice(['A123','M456', 'X789'])
        context = {
            'code': code,
        }
        return JsonResponse(context)
```

**product.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getNewProduct();
});

function getNewProduct() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: 'new-product',
            cache: false,
            success: function (context) {
                displayNewProduct(context);
            }
        }
    );
}

function displayNewProduct(context) {
    var productCode = document.getElementById('product-code');
    productCode.innerText = context.code;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, you have `href="{% url 'new-product' %}"` ? how does your `getNewProduct()` function gets called ?

Comment: @Swati thanks - I've added an onclcick method to the link and it works

Answer (score 0):

I was not calling the function as @Swati pointed out

**product.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    product_link = document.getElementById('product_link')
    product_link.onclick = function(){getNewProduct()};
    getNewProduct();
});
...
```

**html**

```
...
<p><button id="product_link">New Product</button></p>
...
```